# Using Django TestCase, how do I create a test that sends a post request to my view, with data and files for a modelform

Tags: django, file-upload, django-views, django-forms, django-tests

I have browsed SO, google, and have not been able to find a solution that works, or at least understand. I am currently using Django.test.TestCase to implement my tests. I am also using the built-in self.client to send POST requests. I have been successful with model and forms tests up to this point, but now that I am testing my views, I am not able to upload my SimpleUploadedFile image.

I initially created the test in a similar manner to testing my form, with all data in one data dictionary submitted to my POST request. When I received errors, I assumed it was because I needed a second dictionary for 'files'. My research has led me to become more confused on this problem.

I am not sure how to include request.FILES into my POST request or if self.client is simply not able to, and I need to use a third-party library.

The view that I am sending the request to is as follows:

```
# User Profile View
@login_required
def profile_view(request):
    """ This is a User Profile view"""
    
    # POST Method
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserChangeForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
        if 'submitChange' in request.POST:
            if form.is_valid():
                user = request.user
                user.last_modified_by = user 
                user.save()
                form.save()
            else:
                context['changeForm'] = form
                return render(request, 'crm_user/profile.html', context=context)
        
        return redirect('crm_user:profile')
```

(Submitting the form through my local server works as expected)

The form I am currently checking is as follows:

```
# Create User Change Form
class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    """
        Define a Custom UserChangeForm.
    """
    password = None 
    
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('first_name','middle_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'birth_date', 'phone_number', 'profile_photo')
        exclude = ('password',)
```

I have already created tests for my models, and forms, which are working perfectly. I am currently creating tests for my views. The test is as follows:

```
# Create a TestCase for Profile View Post Request
@override_settings(MEDIA_ROOT=MEDIA_ROOT)
class ProfileViewPostTests(TestCase):
    """ Define a TestCase for Profile View Post Request """
    def setUp(self):
        """ Define a setUp for Profile View Post Request """
        self.password = 'P@ssw0rd3x@mpl3'
        self.admin = Admin.objects.create_user(email='admin@example.com', password=self.password)
        self.photo = SimpleUploadedFile("test_image.jpg", b"test_content", "image/jpeg")
        self.files = {
            'profile_photo': self.photo,
        }
        self.changedata = {
            'first_name': 'John',
            'middle_name': 'Jacob',
            'last_name': 'Smith',
            'email': 'jsmith@example.com',
            'birth_date': '1993-04-14',
            'phone_number': '+12124448769',
            # 'profile_photo': self.photo,
            'submitChange': True,
        }

    def test_valid_admin_change_form(self):
        """ Test that a valid CustomUserChangeForm submitted by admin user updates database correctly. """
        # Log in user
        self.client.login(email=self.admin.email, password=self.password)
        
        # Create a Post response for CustomUserChangeForm
        response = self.client.post(reverse('crm_user:profile'), data=self.changedata, files=self.files, content_type= 'multipart/form-data')

        # Check that response status is 302
        print(response)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        
        # Check that database was updated correctly
        admin = Admin.objects.get(id=self.admin.id)
        self.assertEqual(admin.first_name, 'John')
        self.assertEqual(admin.middle_name, 'Jacob')
        self.assertEqual(admin.last_name, 'Smith')
        self.assertEqual(admin.email, 'jsmith@example.com')
        self.assertEqual(admin.birth_date, datetime.date(1993, 4, 14))
        self.assertEqual(admin.phone_number, '+12124448769')
        self.assertEqual(admin.profile_photo, self.photo )
```

I have removed as much code that I feel is unnecessary but so you can still see the whole picture.

If I run the above test I get the error : `self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302) AssertionError: 400 != 302`

Now, I have ran this a few different ways. If i run this test with `response = self.client.post(reverse('crm_user:profile'), data=self.changedata)` my test only fails at `self.assertEqual(admin.profile_photo, self.photo )` , which makes sense because the photo was not uploaded.

If I run the test with `response = self.client.post(reverse('crm_user:profile'), data=self.changedata)` and

```
self.changedata = {
            'first_name': 'John',
            'middle_name': 'Jacob',
            'last_name': 'Smith',
            'email': 'jsmith@example.com',
            'birth_date': '1993-04-14',
            'phone_number': '+12124448769',
            'profile_photo': self.photo,
            'submitChange': True,
        }
```

I receive the following error: `self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302) AssertionError: 200 != 302`

So I added `print(response.context['changeForm'].errors['profile_photo'][0])` to view the error message and received `Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image.`

I have `print(response)` to try and get more information to see what the problem could possibly be, but it only displays `<HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/user/profile/">`

I have also tried

```
# Create a Post response for CustomUserChangeForm
with open('test_image.jpg', "rb") as photo:
        response = self.client.post(reverse('crm_user:profile'), data={
            'first_name': 'John',
            'middle_name': 'Jacob',
            'last_name': 'Smith',
            'email': 'jsmith@example.com',
            'birth_date': '1993-04-14',
            'phone_number': '+12124448769',
            'profile_photo': photo,
            'submitChange': True,
        })
```

But, I received an error `with open('test_image.jpg', "rb") as photo: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test_image.jpg'` which makes sense, since I have no idea where a fake image file would be actually located, to be able to open.

I believe that I can add the SimpleUploadedFile into the data dictionary without needing to have a separate files dictionary, but I am not sure why it is saying the file is not an image or it is corrupted. I used this same syntax for my form validation and the test showed the form was valid with 'profile_photo': self.photo

I feel like there should be a simple solution, and I'm just not understanding how to do this. Please help.